# Using SQLite with WAL

Tags: python, sqlite

I've been following Python documentation on the [SQLite tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html) and I managed to create an `Employee` table and write to it.

```py
import sqlite3
    
conn = sqlite3.connect('employee.db')
c = conn.cursor()
    
firstname = "Ann Marie"
lastname = "Smith"
email = "ams@cia.com"
    
employee = (email, firstname, lastname)
    
c.execute('INSERT INTO Employee Values (?,?,?)', employee)
conn.commit()
    
# Print the table contents
for row in c.execute("select * from Employee"):
    print(row)

conn.close()
```

I've been reading about the [Write-Ahead Logging](https://www.sqlite.org/wal.html), but I can't find a tutorial that explains how to implement it. Can someone provide an example?

I notice Firefox, which uses SQLite, locks the file in such a way that if you attempt to delete the SQLite file while using Firefox, it will fail saying "file is open or being used" (or something similar), how do I achieve this? I'm running Python under Windows 10.

Comment: You didn't notice that the SQLite3 documentation you cite tells you how, using `PRAGMA journal_mode=WAL`?

Comment: @varro - I did but it doesn't work, the WAL file never gets created. According to the documentation it's supposed to be created where the database is located.

Answer (score 8):

```
conn = sqlite3.connect('app.db', isolation_level=None)
```

Set journal mode to WAL:

```
conn.execute('pragma journal_mode=wal')
```

Or another way (just show how to off wal mode)

```
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute('pragma journal_mode=DELETE')
```

Answer (score -1):

The [PRAGMA journal_mode documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_journal_mode) says:

> If the journal mode could not be changed, the original journal mode is returned. […]
>   Note also that the journal_mode cannot be changed while a transaction is active.

So you have to ensure that the database library does not try to be clever and [automatically starts a transaction](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3-controlling-transactions).

Comment: Could you provide an example of how to enable and use WAL with SQLite and Python?